# Hide Cocoapods implementation

Tags: swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I would like to hide the implementation for a framework I'm distributing via Cocoapods, my `.podspec` currently looks like this:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name         = "SomeName"
    s.version      = "0.0.1"
    s.summary      = "Some Summary"
    s.description  = <<-DESC
        some description
    DESC
    s.homepage     = "https://www.some.homepage"
    s.license      = "Some Licence"
    s.author       = { "My Name" => "my@email.address" }
    s.platform     = :ios, "9.0"
    s.source       = { :http => "https://www.some.link.to/my/MyFramework.framework.zip" }
    s.vendored_frameworks = "**/MyFramework.framework"
    s.frameworks = "MyFramework"
    s.xcconfig = { 'FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"$(PODS_ROOT)/MyFramework"' }
    s.preserve_paths = 'MyFramework.framework'
s.so
```

Now I do have two questions:

- what's the difference between `s.source` and the `MyFramework.framework` I have to include in the pod? Which one is taken?
- my pod contains json-files, I tried it out locally and everything works as expected, the json-files are not visible in the client project - how can I hide them in the `.framework`-file as well? The user sees the link to the framework, can download it and sees the json files in there... is there a way to hide this?

Comment: Have you get an answer?

Comment: unfortunately not